# jQuery: Prevent scroll to checkbox on label click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When firing a click event on a label `$('#someOption label').click();`, the page automatically scrolls to the related checkbox (if it is off the viewport), how can i prevent that?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EM28M/1/)

I would try setting the scroll position using jQuery, but my page consists of dynamic elements which means the height of the page is never the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are clicking the label; can you click the checkbox element instead, like:

```
$('#someOption input').click();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A7J6J/

Comment: Ah, switched all my label click event handlers to input click event handlers, and this fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the click even of the label, why not just check the checkbox?

```
$('#someCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Some jquery is executed when clicking the label. I also thought about doing it this way but if there is another way, i'd prefer that.